# Do I have a way to get multiple record in one foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with completely random key, for example:

```
$random_array = array (
    "randomtext" => "randomvalue",
    "apple" => "abc",
    "orange" => "bb",
    "someothertext" => "blue",
    "oxygen" => "bbaa",
    "someothertext" => "don't know what is this",
    "abcdef" => "bbcc",
    "someothertext" => "xxx",
)
```

So, to loop through the array, foreach loop is a must. However, I want to get 2 records in each loop do some processing. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Try again, the question is not clear.

Comment: The array `$random_array` has 8 elements. There are no visible records. Do you want to get two *elements* at a time from `$random_array`?

Comment: #AbraCadaver I got an answer I want, but I am not sure how to improve my question. For better reading for other who are searching for answer, may I have some advice on how to ask it in a better way? (you may guess what I want from the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also chunk/batch them by twos if you really want to process the elements by twos. Example:

```
$random_array = array (
    "randomtext" => "randomvalue",
    "apple" => "abc",
    "orange" => "bb",
    "someothertext1" => "blue",
    "oxygen" => "bbaa",
    "someothertext2" => "don't know what is this",
    "abcdef" => "bbcc",
    "someothertext3" => "xxx",
);

$batches = array_chunk($random_array, 2, true); // batch them by twos, preverse the keys

echo '<pre>';
print_r($batches);

foreach($batches as $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        // do your process here, this will loop twice
    }
}
```

Sidenote: I have to modify your array since some keys are the same. They will overwrite of they are not changed.

Comment: Did you get the question? Are you answering for his problem?

Comment: @ApulGupta yes this is an attempt to answer, why? do you have some suggestions?